# Updating the version of Jasmine used in karma-jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

### Questions

- How can I update the version of [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) used when running [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) via [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) using the [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) plugin?
- Will [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) only get updated whenever the [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) plugin integrates a newer version of [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/), or can I point the [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) plugin to a newer version of [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/)?
- What version of [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) is installed by [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine)?

### Background

I've installed [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html) and [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io) as follows:

```
$ npm install -g generator-angular
$ mkdir myapp && cd $_
$ yo angular
```

Given that `myapp/bower.json` didn't list [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) as one of the [Bower](http://bower.io) installed front-end packages but `myapp/karma.conf.js` listed [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) as the default testing framework, I was surprised the command `grunt test` worked. (The `Gruntfile.js`, `bower.json`, and `karma.conf.js` files were all created as part of the `yo angular` scaffolding process.)

Upon closer inspection of the `myapp/node_modules` packages, I realized that [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) doesn't point to a separate installation of [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/). The [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) plugin actually installs [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/):

```
▼ myapp/
  ▼ karma_jasmine/
    ▼ lib/
        adapter.js
        index.js
        jasmine.js
```

Given that [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) says it is an "*adapter* for the [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) testing framework," I was a little surprised that [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) didn't require us to install [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) separately.

### Package Versions

Here are the various package versions used:

- [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html): "~0.10.8" per `myapp/package.json` contents
- [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine): "~0.1.4" per `myapp/package.json` contents
- [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io): "1.0.6" per `npm list -g | grep yo` command results
- [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/): Unknown but based on a few diffs, I'm almost wondering if [karma-jasmine](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine) includes a customized version of [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) to work with [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/index.html).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can know the jasmine version you are using by running the following Spec:

```js
describe('Test to print out jasmine version', function() {
  it('prints jasmine version', function() {
    console.log('jasmine-version:');
    console.log(jasmine.version || (jasmine.getEnv().versionString && jasmine.getEnv().versionString()));
  });
});
```

and then checking the karma output in your console or browser. It should be something like:

```
LOG: 'jasmine-version:'
LOG: '2.3.4'
```

The jasmine library is included in the jasmine-runner plugin as you've already found out. You can find the exact place where this file is loaded in the source code of the plugin: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/blob/master/lib/index.js (line 7)

You can try to modify the plugin so that an upgrade is possible and send a pull request to karma (see http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/contributing.html)

Comment: looks like there is a pending PR for karma-jasmine 2.0 update: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/pull/18; and as referenced there, for folks using angular also: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/5662

Comment: ...and currentSpec is changed to work for Jasmine 2 in the new release (1.2.11)! https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md.

Comment: The syntax to print the version number seems to differ between v1.3 and v2.0. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658007/how-can-i-confirm-what-version-of-jasmine-im-using/24919927#24919927

Comment: I have updated Karma-Jasmine to 0.3.8 (latest) version but when I try to run the code snippet above to find out the jasmine-core version... it still shows 1.3.1

Answer (score 13):

It a better option to stick to the jasmine version in karma-jasmine and update the whole package.
You can use the following command to get the version of all the installed packages:

```
  npm ls
```

To get the version of the installed global packages:

```
  npm ls -g
```

To view the latest version available on CDN, use:

```
  npm view karma-jasmine version
```

Before updating, you can view all versions at the CDN using:

```
  npm view karma-jasmine versions
```

To install a specific version:

```
  npm install karma-jasmine@~0.2.2
```

(0.2.2 is the latest available).

Comment: This is wrong: `npm view <thing> version` tells you what the _published_ package.json of <thing> says (i.e., what's in the registry), not what you have installed on your machine. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package

Comment: The point of the OP was to determine the version of Jasmine, not the version of the karma-jasmine adapter. They are two very different things.