# How can I confirm what version of Jasmine I'm using?

Tags: unit-testing, version, jasmine, phantomjs, versioning

If I recall there is a command in Jasmine that will log the exact version of Jasmine I'm running to the console, but I can't remember what it is. I am positive I have seen this before somewhere, and now that I actually need it I can't find it anywhere. Does anyone know what it is?

---

Edit: The posted solution of using `jasmine.getEnv().versionString()` isn't working - to any mods reading this, would fixing that issue be better to start as a new question, or continue here?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To simply log the version number try:

```
   if (jasmine.version) { //the case for version 2.0.0
       console.log('jasmine-version:' + jasmine.version);
    }
    else { //the case for version 1.3
       console.log('jasmine-version:' + jasmine.getEnv().versionString());
    }
```

I use this little helper function:

```
 this.isJasmineV2 = function () {
        return (jasmine.version && jasmine.version.charAt(0) === "2");
        //version 1.3 uses this syntax: jasmine.getEnv().versionString()
    };
```

Comment: Ah that explains why I saw two different answers - I hadn't considered the differences in jasmine version. This clears it up, thanks!

Answer (score 53):

command line command:

Detailed view:

```
npm view jasmine
```

or

Version Number:

```
npm view jasmine version
```

Comment: jasmine.version holds the version number

Answer (score 4):

```
describe('Test to print out jasmine version', function() {
it('prints jasmine version', function() {
        console.log('jasmine-version:' + jasmine.getEnv().versionString());
    });
});
```

Source: [Updating the version of Jasmine used in karma-jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730194/updating-the-version-of-jasmine-used-in-karma-jasmine)

Comment: That looks like what I need, but when I run it I get an error: `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jasmine.getEnv().versionString()')
`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try with this line instead `console.log(jasmine.version || (jasmine.getEnv().versionString && jasmine.getEnv().versionString()));`

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the [code](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine.js#L55)

```
jasmine.version
```

should give you the version string.

Answer (score 1):

Do above mentioned or simply go to **jasmine.js** file and look for function **getJasmineRequireObj().version**. This function is returning the version of the jasmine.

Comment: Thank you. I found it in `node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js`: 

`getJasmineRequireObj().version = function() {
  return '3.5.0';
};`