# why is protractor 3.3.0 printing jasmine version 1.3.1?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am using protractor `3.3.0`.

using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24919927/1068746) the output I am getting is `jasmine-version:1.3.1 revision 1354556913`

AFAIK I should be seeing version `2.x`.

looking at the `package.json` files, I see version `2.3.2` is specified..

so why at runtime am I still getting `1.3.1`?

Comment: You should upgrade to latest version of Jasmine and In your Config file specify jasmine version: 
framework: 'jasmine2',

Comment: @Nick nono, this is not needed anymore. Starting from, I think, Protractor 3, `jasmine` in the configuration actually means `jasmine2`.

Comment: Yes, by default it takes Jasmine2 :)

Answer (score 0):

So the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) says everything should be working fine but it doesn't.

I found I can specify `'framework' : 'jasmine2'` in protractor config..

that works well and resolves my problem.

Even though the changelog says you don't have too since `'framework':'jasmine'` will also use jasmine `2.3.2`, it doesn't.

For those still having this problem and cannot upgrade to jasmine 2 for some reason, you can use `throw Error` with `this.isNot`. worked pretty well but I prefer jasmine 2..